# script score function not working but addDecayFunction is working of FunctionScore query

Tags: search, elasticsearch, elastica

I am using Elastica and going to use \Elastica\Query\FunctionScore(); [function score](http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-function-score-query.html) **--> script_score**. Here addDecayFunction() woking fine but addScriptScoreFunction() not work and not through any exception.

DecyFunction is commented because it is working

Here is code

```
$scriptString = "doc['geo_location'].distanceInMiles('42.946697', '-76.113623')";
$script = new \Elastica\Script($scriptString);
$query = new \Elastica\Query\FunctionScore();

$query->addScriptScoreFunction($script);

// $locationOrigin = "32.804654, -117.242594";  
// $locationScale = '2mi';
// $query->addDecayFunction(\Elastica\Query\FunctionScore::DECAY_GAUSS, 'geo_location', $locationOrigin, $locationScale);

$resultSet = $type->search($query); 
$results = $resultSet->getResults();

$totalResults = $resultSet->getTotalHits();

if ( $totalResults > 0 ) {


    echo "<b>Total Results Found are:</b> " . $totalResults . "<br>";
    foreach ( $results as $result ) {

        echo $result->getScore();   
        $data = $result->getData();
        var_dump($data);
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

maybe you forget to enable scripts?

```
script.disable_dynamic: false
```